# What is the difference between "no different" and ''not different"

Tags: grammar, vocabulary

What is the difference between the two following phrase

**I'm no different than any of you**

**I'm not different than any of you**

Comment: There is a large amount of overlap in the meanings but there is a small difference in emphasis. 'Not different' tends to imply that the two are identical whereas 'No different' implies parallelism rather than total congruence. For example a black woman and a white man have obvious physical differences so could not be said to be "Not different from" each other (I'm from the UK, I always say different from) but if they have both held a full driving licence for ten years without any traffic convictions their driving qualifications are "No different from" each other.